# Python Multiprocessing Saving Files

Tags: python, function, multiprocessing, save, output

I am computing various parameters across the entirety of Antarctica. The code takes too long so I have decided to split up Antarctica into 8 separate bits and run the code for each of these separate bits in parallel. At the end of each file I get a dictionary 'I' which I would like to save.

The 'function file' is like this:

```
I = {}
def function()

   ... code to compute variables ...

    PKL_paths_save = 'path'

    file_save = 'file_name' + change_name

    f = open(PKL_paths_save + file_save, "wb")

    pickle.dump(D, f)

    f.close()
```

And the multiprocessing file looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing
from 'function file' import function

file = 'file_name'

PKL_paths = 'path'

D = pd.read_pickle(PKL_paths + file)

S = range(0,361, 45)

if __name__ == '__main__':

     a = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[0], S[1], 1))
     b = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[1], S[2], 2))
     c = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[2], S[3], 3))
     d = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[3], S[4], 4))
     e = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[4], S[5], 5))
     f = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[5], S[6], 6))
     g = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[6], S[7], 7))
     h = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[7], S[8], 8))


     i = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[0], S[1], 1))
     j = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[1], S[2], 2))
     k = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[2], S[3], 3))
     l = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[3], S[4], 4))
     m = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[4], S[5], 5))
     n = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[5], S[6], 6))
     o = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[6], S[7], 7))
     p = multiprocessing.Process(target=function, args=(S[7], S[8], 8))

     a.start()
     b.start()
     c.start()
     d.start()
     e.start()
     f.start()
     g.start()
     h.start()
     i.start()
     j.start()
     k.start()
     l.start()
     m.start()
     n.start()
     o.start()
     p.start()

     a.join()
     b.join()
     c.join()
     d.join()
     e.join()
     f.join()
     g.join()
     h.join()
     i.join()
     j.join()
     k.join()
     l.join()
     m.join()
     n.join()
     o.join()
     p.join()

     print(a)
```

So basically what is happening is there is 8 'function file' processes happening at once for each bit of Antarctica. But when we get to the end of the file, I get a memory error and I think that is because it is trying to save 8 files at once.

Is there a solution to this problem? Is there a way to run the code in parallel but save the results in series (one after the other)? Or is there a way to combine the dictionaries (I) of all 8 bits of Antarctica into one dictionary and save that in one file?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Please note the S list refers to the longitude of Antarctica and how they have been divided into separate bits of Antarctica. The third variable in the 'args' is the change_name variable so they are saved to different files.

EDIT:

[Here is a screenshot of the error. isotope and isotope_nf are the functions imported from the function file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rajSp.png)

Comment: Please provide explanations as to what you have tried so far, as to avert suggestions that already failed.
For example, are you sure that the file name is always different/that 8 files are actually created?
Can you provide the exact error that is thrown?
Does it work when you only let the process of one of the eight parts compute? Meaning instead of computing all 8/8 you just comment 7 of them out.

Comment: Yes I have now tried both and the error still is present. I tried to create a new function to purely save the files but then this wasn't working because the dictionary was not defined in the function to save the file.

Comment: Since the error still exists, that should pretty safely rule out the multiprocessing aspect. Since it's a `MemoryError`, I'm suspecting it has something to do with the size your input/output data and the pickling of said data. You should update your question with the _exact_ error, with Traceback, that you get when running.

Comment: I have now updated my question with the error message I am getting. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now got this problem working with just using joblib instead of pickle.